# Angular reverse model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have some code that generates html. In that HTML I use my directive. And behaviour that directive should depend on some value (NB: that is a tooltip that will be called from non Angular part)
So I generate the code like :

```
  <div my-directive item=controllerFunction(value)>
```

where value is a parameter

Later in directive I will have

```
      return {

        restrict:'A',
        templateUrl :'Tralala.html',
     .....
```

And Item should be an object that I plan to get from Controller through some function controllerFunction(value)

So in template I will have an object that I will be able to use while rendering my directive.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create directive isolated scope configuration with 'item' in it:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        templateUrl :'Tralala.html',
    };
});
```

Then local directive scope will be augmented with `item` property and in directive template you can use it like this:

```
<div>{{item}}</div>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/QQDuUBROdlmjEoKdvQvB?p=preview

Comment: OK:    I have an Item in directive and some function in controller. How in template call  'controllerFunction(item)'? and get the data I need?

Comment: At least how just to output Item in template?

Comment: Check the demo, you can simply output it like `{{item}}`.

Comment: ok. I will ask the other way: I have  <div my-directive value=10> In Template I need <div Item= CtrlFunc(value)></div> But value here is in directive context. I need to ask controller to get from array an object with id that I have in value

Comment: where is `CtrlFunc` is defined?

Comment: that function is in controller

Comment: the issue - I have non-Angular code that is able produce some HTML and knows about selected Id - I need to get an object according this ID from Controller and put it into Template.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need 2 attributes: the `value` and the `ctrlFunction` that is to be called somewhere like this: `ctrlFunction(value)`. So I'd create one directive that uses 2 attributes and makes the call whenever you want it.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'A',
        scope: {
            ctrlFunc: '=',
            value: '='
        },
        templateUrl :'Tralala.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            // Create the nasty DOM event listeners and the ctrlFunc call here
        }
    };
});
```